# Correct PUT method with spring-boot and spring-data

Tags: java, rest, spring-boot, spring-data, put

I'm using Spring Boot and Spring Data to build RESTful API. I have two entities: `Site` and `Floor`. There are several `Floors` in one `Site`. I'm wondering what is the correct way to make a PUT method? So far I have this method in `SiteController.class`:

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.PUT, value = "/api/sites")
    public void updateSite(@RequestBody Site site){
        sitesService.updateSite(site);
    }
```

And this is `SitesService.class`:

```
public void updateSite(Site site) {
        sitesRepository.save(site);
    }
```

Model `Site.class` has `id` and `name`.

When I send following JSON with PUT method to `/api/sites`...

```
{
  "id": 1,
  "name": "SITE 1"
}
```

...I get update updated `Site` entity as expected.

But I'm wondering whether this implementation is right or not?
Shouldn't I specify an id of the Site in URI that I'm going to update with PUT? Like this: `/api/sites/{id}`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my opinion, you can sent the PUT request with `/api/sites/{id}`, in the controller method, you can use the id to get the entity from the repository, change the property "name" and then save it in the repository.

Comment: Thanks. Was thinking about the same approach.